# How to refer a block in an image?

Tags: notation

I have an image $I$ with size $X,Y$. I want to refer to a varticle stripe of the image between column $S_1$ and $S_2$. In matlab we write it as,

$B = I(:,S_1:S_2)$

But how to write in mathematical notation ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $S_1\le x\le S_2, 0\le y\le Y$

Comment: Incidentally, I have seen numerical analysis books use Fortran-like matrix notation in proofs (or matlab-like if you prefer, it's more or less the same), it does not seem to be a problem.